# how to request money at customer's phonePe account (android , Java)

Tags: java, android, payment-processing, upi

I am working on POS(GST billing system)system App
and I need to add "**PhonePe**" payment mode at checkout time (like **reliance fresh pos system** use ,they ask customer number and then send money request on that number )
If any one know how can I implement this payment mode in my project please help me ;

Comment: Did you try to google the same ? Also, please mention the different approaches you have tried and the specific problems you are facing with an approach.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @AnikethJain yes but not found that much relative  content so I shift to paytm  , yesterday  i found dynamic QRcode generation via paytm api                                       
At -https://business.paytm.com/docs/dynamic-qr-code-payments/                                                         and i contact Paytm but they didn't response yet

Comment: You can go through these for PhonePe Android integration https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/docs/androidintent-sdk-integration